# Android push notification with actions/parameters

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe6

I just made an app with Delphi XE6 that receives push notifications with kinvey based on [this example](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/sarinadupont/2014/04/16/remote-push-notifications-on-android-with-rad-studio-xe6/)

When the application is running and I send a push the PushEvent handler receives it well, but when the application is closed and I press the notification it only opens my app.

Can I know which notification was pressed and get parameters from it?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I get a little bit closer, in my FormCreate ask for Extras:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  LIntent: JIntent;
  LExtras: JBundle;
  LExtrasArray: TJavaObjectArray<AndroidApi.JNI.JavaTypes.JObject>;
begin
  LIntent := SharedActivity.getIntent;
  try
    if LIntent <> nil then
    begin
      LExtras := LIntent.getExtras;
      if LExtras <> nil then
      begin
        //Now try to get the data
        LExtrasArray := LExtras.KeySet.toArray;
        for I := 0 to LExtrasArray.Length - 1 do
          Memo1.Lines.Add(JStringToString(LExtrasArray.Items[I].toString));
      end;
    end;
  finally 
    LIntent := nil;
  end;
end;
```

With this code I get "gcm" in my memo.
So, when the notification fires my app I get this Extra available.

Now the problem is how I get info about that extra?
I tried `LExtras.getString(StringToJString('message'))` but this writes '' instead of the push message

Answer (score 1):

Sarina DuPont answer me in her [Blog](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/sarinadupont/2014/04/16/remote-push-notifications-on-android-with-rad-studio-xe6/#comment-2005)

`PushEvents` component has a property `StartupNotification` for this purpose

```
procedure TMainForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(PushEvents.StartupNotification) then
    //Do something here!
    //for example 
    //Memo.Text := PushEvents.StartupNotification.Message;
end;
```